# Dynamic bit-based flattening of multiple rows by pivoting into additional columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  | Value
-----------
1   |   a 
1   |   b 
2   |   a
2   |   c
3   |   a
3   |   d
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
ID  | Value_a  |  Value_b | Value_c | Value_d
---------------------------------------------
1   |    1     |     1    |    0    |    0
2   |    1     |     0    |    1    |    0
3   |    1     |     0    |    0    |    1
```

I think a dynamic conditional aggregation is required. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation of dynamic conditional aggregation:

```
--create test table
create table #values (
     [ID] int
    ,[Value] char(1))

--populate test table
insert into #values
values
     (1, 'a') 
    ,(1, 'b') 
    ,(2, 'a')
    ,(2, 'c')
    ,(3, 'a')
    ,(3, 'd')

--declare variable that will hold dynamic query
declare @query nvarchar(max) = ' select [ID] '

--build dynamic query and assign it to variable 
select 
    @query = @query + max(',max(case when [value] = ''' 
    + [value] + ''' then 1 else 0 end) as Value_' + [value] ) 
from 
    #values 
group by 
    [value]

--add group by clause to dunamic query
set  @query = @query + ' from #values group by [id]'

--execute dynamic query
exec (@query)
```

this is the result:

[image]

Now you can add a value (for example id = 4 and value = 'e') replacing the original insert with this one:

```
insert into #values
values
     (1, 'a') 
    ,(1, 'b') 
    ,(2, 'a')
    ,(2, 'c')
    ,(3, 'a')
    ,(3, 'd')
    ,(4, 'a')
    ,(4, 'e')
```

this is the new output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Conditional aggregation goes like:

```
select 
    id,
    max(case when value = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) value_a,
    max(case when value = 'b' then 1 else 0 end) value_b,
    max(case when value = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) value_c,
    max(case when value = 'd' then 1 else 0 end) value_d
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: This is dynamic?

Comment: @Daniel: no (but that does not mean it has to downvoted, does it?). If you want to return different columns depending on your data, then you need dynamic SQL (essentially, construct a SQL query in a string variable, then execute it). This task is usually a better fit for applications than for databases.

Comment: Yes, I think answers that do not directly address the question should be downvoted. Simply giving a conditional aggregation and saying "go figure out the dynamic sql yourself or use an application" in the subtext is not what was asked in the question, right? If your answer is "this task is usually better fit for applications than databases", then that's what you should answer. That said, fwiw, my use of sql is not for application consumption, it's for SSAS consumption, so I don't find that response acceptable either. But I would not downvote the latter because that was unknown.